# Using hasPermission inside @Query

Tags: spring-security, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-el

I am trying to annotate a Spring Data Repository `findAll()` method with a custom `@Query` annotation. I want to use the Spring Security `hasPermission()` expression inside the `where` clause.

I have initialized the `SecurityEvaluationContextExtension` bean to allow usage of common built-in security expressions in SpEL.

```java
@Bean
public SecurityEvaluationContextExtension securityEvaluationContextExtension() {
    return new SecurityEvaluationContextExtension();
}
```

I am using a custom `PermissionEvaluator` implementation.

```java
@Query("select t from #{#entityName} t where 1=?#{hasPermission(filterObject, 'read') ? 1 : 0}")
Page<Stream> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

I get below exception. It seems `hasPermission` is not accessible for some reason. `hasRole` works just fine.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'filterObject' cannot be found on object of type 'java.lang.Object[]' - maybe not public?
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:226)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:94)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:81)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getArguments(MethodReference.java:155)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:85)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:171)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.Ternary.getValueInternal(Ternary.java:51)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:132)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:297)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SpelExpressionStringQueryParameterBinder.evaluateExpression(SpelExpressionStringQueryParameterBinder.java:139)
```

What is the correct way to use `hasPermission` inside a SpEL expression in `@Query`?

Answer (score -1):

The problem here is that filterObject is in fact the Page instance returned by your repository method

To be able to use it, something like that should be done

```
@Query("select t from #{#entityName} t where 1=?#{hasPermission(entity, 'read') ? 1 : 0}")
Page<Stream> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

where entity is equal to an instance returned by your query.

Sadly, it doesn't seem that it's possible for the moment. I am still searching