# Java Spring Security @PostFilter performance

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

My Java Spring application, which uses ACLs, has a service method to retrieve all the objects corresponding to a given user:

```java
    @Override
    @PostFilter("hasPermission(filterObject, 'READ') or hasPermission(filterObject, 'ADMINISTRATION')")
    public List<SomeClass> findAll() {
        return SomeClassRepository.findAll();
    }
```

Unfortunately, where there are many objects in the database, this method takes too much time to complete (over 1 second). Probably because it will first fetch all the objects from the database, and then filter them one by one in memory. How can I optimize this without losing the benefits of Spring ACLs?

Edit: the solution I came up with for now is to create repositories for the `acl_sid` and `acl_entry` repositories and to fetch the IDs of the object of interest through those repositories. This gives me a 10x improvement in execution time compared to the method above. The new code looks like this:

```java
    @Override
    @PostFilter("hasPermission(filterObject, 'READ') or hasPermission(filterObject, 'ADMINISTRATION')")
    public List<SomeClass> findAll() {
        List<SomeClass> result = new ArrayList<SomeClass>();
        Long userId = (Long) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        AclSid sid = aclSidRepository.findBySid(Long.toString(userId));
        List<AclEntry> aclEntries = aclEntryRepository.findBySid(sid);
        for (AclEntry aclEntry : aclEntries) {
            AclObjectIdentity aclObjectIdentity = aclEntry.getAclObjectIdentity();
            AclClass aclClass = aclObjectIdentity.getObjectIdClass();
            if (aclClass.getClassName().equals("com.company.app.entity.SomeClass")) {
                Optional<SomeClass> SomeClass = SomeClassRepository
                        .findById(aclObjectIdentity.getObjectIdIdentity());
                if (SomeClass.isPresent()) {
                    result.add(SomeClass.get());
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: How often do these objects change?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli those are user-editable objects, so they can change anytime

Comment: You might have to move hasPermission(...) inside your repository to optimize it, have a look at this if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49058363/using-haspermission-inside-query

Comment: and use the Pageable approach in the repository when you moved the permission check conditions into the query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Spring filters the information in memory the performance will depend on the actual number of results: if there is a large amount of them, I am afraid that perhaps only caching your repository results before filtering the information may be a suitable solution.

To deal with the problem, you can filter the results at the database level. Two approaches come to my mind:

- Either use `Specification`s, and filter the results at the database level taking into account the information about the principal exposed by Spring Security `SecurityContext` and including the necessary filter `Predicates` in order to restrict the information returned.
- Or, if you are using Hibernate, use [entity filters](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-filter) to again, based on the information about the principal exposed by Spring Security, apply the necessary data restrictions. Please, see [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65995484/intercept-repository-method-calls-in-spring-data-refining-the-query-on-the-fly/65997737#65997737) which provides great detail about the solution.

Please, consider for instance the use case of the Spring Data `Specification`s.

Instead of `SomeClass`, let's suppose that we are working with bank accounts. Let's create the corresponding entity:

```java
@Entity
public class BankAccount {

  @Id
  private String accountNumber;
  private Float balance;
  private String owner;
  private String accountingDepartment;

  //...

}
```

And the corresponding repository:

```java
public interface BankAccountRepository extends Repository<BankAccount, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<BankAccount, String> {
}
```

In order to filter the information depending on the user who is performing the query, we can define an utility method that, based on the user permissions, returns a `List` of `Predicates` that we can add later to the ones we are using in a certain `Specification` when filtering the bank accounts:

```java
public static List<Predicate> getPredicatesForRestrictingDataByUser(Root<BankAccount> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
  // I realized in your edit that you are returning the user id instead of the user object.
  // There is nothing wrong with it but you are losing a valuable information: if you provide
  // a convenient UserDetails implementation you can have direct access to the authorities a user has, etc
  User user = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

  // Restrict data based on actual permissions

  // If the user is an admin, we assume that he/she can see everything, and we will no return any predicates
  if (hasAuthority(user, 'ADMINISTRATION')) {
    return Collections.emptyList();
  }

  // Let's introduce the accounting manager role.
  // Suppose that an accounting manager can see all the accounts in his/her department
  if (hasAuthority(user, 'ACCOUNTING_MANAGER')) {
    return Collections.singletonList(cb.equal(root.get(BankAccount_.accountingDeparment), user.getDepartment()))
  }

  // In any other case, a user can only see the bank account if he/she is the account owner
  return Collections.singletonList(cb.equal(root.get(BankAccount_.owner), user.getId()));
}
```

Where `hasAuthority` can look like:

```java
public static boolean hasAuthority(User user, String... authorities) {
  if (user instanceof UserDetails) {
    for (String authority : authorities) {
      return authentication.getAuthorities().stream()
        .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
        .findAny(a -> a.equals(authority))
        .isPresent();
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

Now, use these methods when constructing your `Specification`s. Consider for instance:

```java
public static Specification<BankAccount> getBankAccounts(final BankAccountFilter filterCriteria) {
  return new Specification<BankAccount>() {

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<BankAccount> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
      List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

      // Build your predicate list according to the user provided filter criteria
      String accountNumber = filterCriteria.getAccountNumber();
      if (accountNumber != null) {
        predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get(BankAccount_.accountNmber), accountNumber);
      }

      //...

      // And now, restrict the information a user can see
      // Ideally, define getPredicatesForRestrictingDataByUser in a generic class more suitable for being reused
      List<Predicate> predicatesForRestrictingDataByUser = getPredicatesForRestrictingDataByUser(root, query, cb);
      predicates.addAll(predicatesForRestrictingDataByUser);

      Predicate predicate = cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
      return predicate;
    }
  };
}
```

Please, forgive me for the simple use case, but I hope you get the idea.

The solution proposed in his comment by @OsamaAbdulRehman looks interesting as well, although I honestly never tested it.

Comment: Hi @jccampanero, thanks for your answer but I find it difficult to understand the solutions you're proposing. A few examples would probably be helpful.

Comment: HI @geschema. You are welcome. Of course, please, see the updated answer, I hope it helps. Please, let me know if you need further clarifications.